# Monotone Convergence Theorem For Functions

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to do an alternative proof for one part of the Monotone Convergence Theorem. The way that we did the proof in my course makes sense to me, but I like to try and do proofs differently to identify misunderstandings in my own thinking. I will state part of the MCT below, and then demonstrate how I have done this 'alternative' for the left-sided limit. My approach relies on the definition of a one-sided limit and that $f$ preserves the convergence of sequences. It would be helpful to get some feedback on if the approach makes sense, and if not, why not?

---

The first part of the Monotone Convergence Theorem is stated as follows:

*Let $f(a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$* and $f$ is bounded in $\mathbb{R}$:

1. *If $f$ is increasing then $\lim_{x \to b^{-}}=sup \, f$ and $\lim_{x \to a^{+}}=inf \, f$*

*Proof:*

Let $f(a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$. Since $f$ is increasing and bounded in $\mathbb{R}$ it follows that $sup \, f$ exists and that $sup f = f(b)$. I now claim $\lim_{x \to b^{-}}=sup \, f = f(b)$ exists.

Now let $\epsilon >0$ and choose $\delta = \dfrac{1}{n}$. Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence such that for all $n \geq n_0, \,  n,n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$, we can find $x_n \in (b - \delta, b)$, i.e. $x_n \in (b - \dfrac{1}{n}, b)$. It follows that $b - \dfrac{1}{n} < x_n < b$, and by the Squeeze Theorem $x_n \to b$. Because functions preserve convergence it follows that $f(x_n) \to f(b)$.

Hence, $\lim_{x \to b^{-}}=sup \, f = f(b)$

---

I know there are alternative ways to prove this, but as I mentioned, I'm just looking for some criticism on this particular approach. Maybe I am missing an explicit assumption? Perhaps there's a flaw in the reasoning? Feel free to let me know.

Comment: Attention, $f(b)$ is not defined (since the domain of $f$ is the open interval $(a,b)$, so $a,b$ are excluded). What you proved is that you can construct a sequence $x_n$ converging to $b$ and that $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(b)$ (which again is not defined).

Comment: Hint: To prove that $\lim_{x\rightarrow b^-}f(x)=\sup f$, prove that $f(c)\leqslant \lim_{x\rightarrow b^-}f(x)$ for all $c\in(a,b)$ (here is fundamental that $f$ is $increasing$, so $f(c)\leqslant f(d)$, for all $d\geqslant c$)

Comment: @Alessandro This approach you are suggesting is similar to how we did it in class. I would like to try and keep the proof using convergent sequences just for the sake of practice with the concepts, but I may need to abandon the idea. I'll do some more thinking.

Comment: Well, by definition of $s=\sup f$, there is a sequence $x_n\in(a,b)$ such that $|s-f(x_n)|<\frac{1}{n}$. It's trivial that $\lim_{x\rightarrow b^-}f(x)\leqslant s$, so you can prove that it's absurd that $\lim_{x\rightarrow b^-}f(x)<s$ (for example, by noticing that the strict disequality imply there is $\lim_{x\rightarrow b^-}f(x)<f(x_n)\leqslant s$)

Comment: Yeah I think that's another way to go about it. I'll play around with that idea for the other parts of the proof.